# couldn't find any FORWARD chain REJECT entry in proxy/iptables/proxier.go but somehow it shows up in the node iptables

Tags: kubernetes

I have a new k8s install (kube-proxy iptable mode) and trying to learn how iptables is done. I noticed this entry in the FORWARD chain,
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

looking at proxy/iptables/proxier.go, nothing could have added above entry as far as I can tell. How did that entry is added there? The following is the entire FORWARD chain,

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-FORWARD  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes forwarding rules */
KUBE-SERVICES  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW /* kubernetes service portals */
DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
FORWARD_direct  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
ACCEPT     all  --  10.244.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.244.0.0/16

The k8s is 1.15.2 release.

Answer (score 0):

it turns out this entry was added by firewalld in centos7 by default.